# Set mask in modal form

Tags: jquery, mask

I'm trying to add masks with masked input plugin in a modal form but I'm struggling to do it. I do not know exactly why it's not working, Could someone help me telling me what's wrong with the code?

```
<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="cadastromodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close"
            data-dismiss="modal">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
            Cadastrar novo contato
        </h4>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">

        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="cadastrocontato.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label"
                for="inputEmail3" id="nome">Nome</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="nome" name="nome" class="form-control"
                    id="nome" placeholder="Nome"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label"
                for="inputEmail3">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control"
                    id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label"
                for="inputEmail3" id="telefone">Telefone</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="telefone" name="telefone" maxlength="10" class="form-control"
                    id="telefone" placeholder="Telefone"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label"
                for="inputEmail3">Celular</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="celular" name="celular"  maxlength="10" class="form-control"
                    id="celular" placeholder="Celular"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal Footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
            data-dismiss="modal">
            Cancelar
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"   data-toggle="modal">
            Cadastrar
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
 jQuery(function($){
        $("#Telefone").mask("(99) 9999-9999");
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: `id` is case-sensitive; substitute `$("#telefone")` for `$("#Telefone")`